# Different style in lightning from sandbox to production

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I developped a quick lightning component that is embedded in a visualforce page and so far everything is fine. Look wise though, it seems like some styles aren't migrating correctly from my Sandbox environment and the Production environment, both running the exact same code.

Here are a quick overview of the difference that I see in the data table (from the lightning design system):

*Sandbox version with correct styling*
[image: Sandbox version with correct styling]

*Production version with mising styles*
[image]

As you can see, the production version seems to be bland and missing a bunch of table styles. Both are running the exact same code, with the standard styles removed from the Visualforce page.

Is there anything I am missing? I tried to look for updates but I am a bit puzzled by this.

Comment: How are you linking the SLDS styles?  extends="force:slds" or hardcoding to a certain version..

Comment: Actually I used extends="force:slds" before embedding the component in a visualforce page, after which I changed it to the lightning out. I feared indeed that it would remove the lightning design styling but it was fine. I even made sure that nothing was cached. Upon deployment to production, only part of the style seems to be applied which I find odd (I would expect all or nothing I guess).

Comment: Are you using the new `__` rather than the old `--` styles? (ie if the css in your markup uses the new style definitions, then the older stylesheet in production work work on some of that.

Comment: Are you production vs. sandbox different version?

Comment: Hmm that might be it indeed, they are Spring 17 and Summer 17, even though its a fresh full sandbox, I wrongly assumed they'd be identical. I am using the new ones from the lightning design website.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Just looked through the change and you were right indeed the last change replaced all doubled dash with a single underscore. Writing the component that way on the sandbox by replacing underscore by double dash fixes the problem (although definitely not ideal but at least I know the problem).

BenjaminPirih Thanks for noting the version difference, didn't see it at first glance!

Either of you can submit an answer regarding versioning and the LDS change and I'll accept it to close the question, thanks!

Comment: Ok done - new answer added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lightning Design System team recently made a change to the css that they output for a specific reason - `--` chars in lightning components can't be commented out due to the way the xhtml parser interprets the file - so you were left with the choice of either replacing the `--` chars (with say `^^`) or pulling the markup completely.

The new markup gets around that problem by using `__` instead.

However, at the moment, production css is still using the old `--` css.

If you upload a new Lightning component to production using the new css style, it won't be understood as a valid css rule, so hence won't get the style you were after.